# How to echo out content from a MySQL Table Column

Tags: php, mysql, fetch

I have for some time tried to create a admin panel view of things where a user can insert things to then get posted on the website. Kind of a smaller version of wordpress, right now mostly for private and educational use. However, I can't get it to post the content that is sent to the database from the adminpanel view of things. It won't display anything at all, which makes me think I am doing something *critically* wrong.

This is what I got : (Connection)

```
   <?php
session_start();

$adress = 'Host adress goes here';
$dbusername = 'Database username goes here';
$dbpassword = 'Database password goes here';

$anslutning = mysqli_connect($host, $dbusername, $dbpassword);
if (!$anslutning) die ("<br /><b>Can't connect to server</b>");

$anslutning->select_db('Database name goes here') or die ("Could not connect to database");

    ?>
```

And the code I currently can't get to work

```
<p class="welcometext">
    <?php

        $getContentQuery = "SELECT content FROM tblPages";

        if ($getContent = $anslutning->prepare($getContentQuery)) {



        $getContent->execute();
        $result = $anslutning->query($getContentQuery);

        while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

            echo $rows[2];


        }
    }




    ?>
</p>
```

**EDIT:**I just realised it does not echo out anything inside the if statement, so as a newbie to PHP I'm not sure if it is supposed to do so, or if this is why 'while' is not working.

**EDIT2:** So I have gotten my answer and ticket it. However, I need to add something to it. While what I had written was wrong from the beginning, removing all earlier PHP code seemed to fix the problem (Let the troubleshooting commence!). I appreciate everyones help and time, and as long as i can figure what is breaking it, the issue is solved.

Comment: Where is your database connection??? May be you are mixing mysql and mysqli !!

Comment: What is this $post[2]

Comment: You say `prepare` but I think you mean `query`

Comment: @Saty I wrote above the code that I have the connection higher up in the code. It works with other PHP code, so I doubt it.

Comment: @raveenanigam It was mixed up between rows and post, fixed it up but did not fix the problem itself.

Comment: try this $rows[content]

Comment: Nope. Nothing @raveenanigam

Comment: I agree with @SuperDJ. Looks like you are getting mixed up between mysql and PDO

Comment: @foxbeefly Could very well be. As someone quite new to PHP trying to do something, mixing up two ways of doing it wouldn't exactly surprise me. I feel like prepare should work on MySQLi though, no?

Comment: show us where you define `$anslutning` first

Comment: @Alex $anslutning would be the connection, edit of that coming up on the main post however.

Comment: don't spend your time on useless comments, just show your code ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if ($getContent = $anslutning->prepare($getContentQuery)) {
     $getContent->execute();
     $content='';
     $getContent->bind_result($content);
     while ($getContent->fetch()) {
        echo $content;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are echoing $post which seems not to exist. Echo out $rows

Comment: Missed that line completely. Thanks for pointing it out! Did not seem to help, however.